# Cross compile php with OPcache support error

Tags: php, cross-compiling, opcache

Lately I came across this error while cross-compiling php with opcache enabled. Here is a short log:

```
checking whether to enable Zend OPcache support... yes
checking for mprotect... yes
checking for sysvipc shared memory support... no
checking for mmap() using MAP_ANON shared memory support... no
checking for mmap() using /dev/zero shared memory support... no
checking for mmap() using shm_open() shared memory support... no
checking for mmap() using regular file shared memory support... no
checking "whether flock struct is linux ordered"... configure: error: in `/opt/php/php-7.0.9':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
See `config.log' for more details
```

How can I do to resolve it? Any piece of information is much appreciated.

Comment: Share what you did here instead of letting us go to some random external website.

Comment: It seems that PHP with opcache enabled can never be CROSS COMPILED with `--host=arm-linux`, that's all I want to address and hope to solve..